# Getting RIGHT JOIN with intermediate table with Django ORM?

Tags: python, django

I have these models:

```py
class Region(models.Model):
    region_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.region_name

class GameRegionRelease(models.Model):
    region = models.ForeignKey(
        Region,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='region'
    )
    game = models.ForeignKey(
        Game,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='game'
    )
    release_date = models.DateField(
        verbose_name='release date',
        default=None
    )

class Game(models.Model):
    game_name = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    release_dates = models.ManyToManyField(
        Region,
        related_name='game_release_dates',
        through='GameRegionRelease'
    )
```

What I'm looking to get is every region listed for every game, even if there is no region data for that game.  So the results would be Game x Region, with the region data filled in by GameRegionRelease where available.  I'd want something similar to what the following would produce:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM gameslist_region gr 
CROSS JOIN gameslist_game gg
LEFT JOIN gameslist_gameregionrelease grr
  ON gg.game_name = grr.game_id 
  AND gr.region_name = grr.region_id;
```

But I don't know how to express this in Django using native ORM constructs.  Is this possible?  I'm using Python 3.6.4 and Django 2.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

```
## Get all objects of GameRegionRelease
game_region_release = GameRegionRelease.objects.all()

## to access game_name
game_region_release.game.game_name

## to access region_name
game_region_release.region.region_name
```

Comment: So if regions listed, say, "PAL", "Japan" and "North America", and there was a game that only had an entry for Japan, I would then get output for PAL and North America as well, just with no release_date data?  I wouldn't want it so that it only outputs Japan.  I'd expect 3 rows for each game, whether they have no regions, 1 region, 2 or 3.  So the lack of an entry in GameRegionRelease wouldn't change the number of rows.

Comment: I haven't checked but:

game_region_release = GameRegionRelease.objects.filter(region=region, game=game).select_related()

Should grab every instance.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work:
    >>> game_region_release = GameRegionRelease.objects.filter(region=region, game=game).select_related()
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
    NameError: name 'region' is not defined

Comment: Yeah , First get all elements of game and region.
region = Region.objects.all()
game = Game.objects.all()
and the use above query
game_region_release = GameRegionRelease.objects.filter(region=region, game=game).select_related()

Comment: Hmm... that gives me: `ValueError: The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.`